# poems/phrases/quotes/sayings/idioms/stories/allegories: evil vs. good

Tags: word-requests

Evil vs. good is the theme of most (slightly exaggerated) works.

The list of works I have only contain things like:

> 天下乌鸦一般黑
>
> 老鼠过街，人人喊打
>
> 臭味相投
>
> 狼狈为奸

but these are all mostly just talking about evil itself and not comparing/contrasting the two.

Any stories/allegories or poems and phrases/quotes/sayings about the evil vs. good would be most welcomed.

edit: 邪不能胜正 is good...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to **contrast** the good & evil, i would suggest the pairs of "君子" vs "小人" & "善" vs "惡".

論語﹒述而

```
君子坦蕩蕩﹒小人長戚戚
```

莊子﹒山木

```
君子之交淡若水﹒小人之交甘若醴
```

國語﹒周語下

```
從善如登﹒從惡如崩
```

公羊傳﹒昭公二十年

```
君子之善善也長﹒惡惡也短﹒惡惡止其身﹒善善及子孫
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many phrases and quotes mentioned good and evil, I personally like these two the most.

> http://www.sutrapearls.org/proverbs/pr12/pr12_02.htm#sthash.2b7sB2J5.dpbs

「**善惡到頭終有報, 只爭來早與來遲**」 this is a 佛門諺語 (Buddhist proverb)

variant:

「**善有善報，惡有惡報，若然不到，時辰未到**」 this one is a 打油詩 (doggerel)

"The universe will reward good deed and punish evil deed eventually. It is just a matter of time."

> http://baike.baidu.com/view/114296.htm

「**勿以惡小而為之，勿以善小而不為**」 (quote from Lui Bei, Shu Han founder, 161 AD-223 AD)

"Do not think it is fine to commit a sin because it is just a minor one; Do not think it is useless to do a good deed because it is too small"

Others: ( mostly heard in martial art movies nowadays)

「改邪歸正」 (reform from wicked to decent)

「行俠仗義，儆惡除奸」( uphold justice with selflessness, deter evil and remove the wicked)

「邪不勝正」(evil cannot defeat justice)

「自古正邪不兩立」(since the ancient time, justice and evil cannot coexist)

Answer (score 1):

邪不能胜正 has variants: 邪不胜正; 邪不敌正.

Here are a few other sayings.

- 祸福无常 (disaster and happiness do not follow rules (idiom); future blessings and misfortunes are unpredictable)
- 善有善报，恶有恶报 (virtue has its reward, evil its retribution.) One can also add this: 若然不报时晨未到 (The payback is just a matter of time).

Also, some examples of contrasting 义 and 利; justice/righteousness with profit. I think it's related to the question.

- 见利忘义
- 见利思义
- 重利轻义
- 君子喻于义，小人喻于利 (Confucious).

Answer (score 0):

Came across these today and thought of this thread. Hope it helps!

孟子：性善论
荀子：性恶论

http://wenku.baidu.com/view/8533904ca45177232f60a23b.html?from=search